# A procedure as an If condition

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I have an if clause in a procedure with a  nother procedure as a condition like this
`If procedure(a, b) then`.

Is it possible with the algorithm package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \If{procedure($a,b$)}
        \State do something
    \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```